# plot regression line, abline

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot

```
plot(wine$AGST ~ wine$Price, xlab="Price", ylab = "AGST", pch = 19)
```

and want to draw a regression line ie

```
abline(lm(Price ~ AGST, data=wine))
```

but facing error ie

> abline(mod01)
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>     "lm" is not a graphical parameter
>   2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>     "lm" is not a graphical parameter
>   abline(lm(Price ~ AGST, data=wine))
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>     "lm" is not a graphical parameter
>   2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>     "lm" is not a graphical parameter
>   abline(lm(Price ~ AGST, data=wine))
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>     "lm" is not a graphical parameter
>   2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>     "lm" is not a graphical parameter

Comment: Your code should work: reproducible example `plot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$wt) ;  abline(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))` (note: I think your lm variables should be reversd `lm(AGST ~ Price, data=wine)`)

Answer (score 1):

Please provide reproducible example. 
Here is one example from mtcars data

Keep in mind that 
The plot (A ~ B) plots A as Y axis and B as X axis
While plot(A , B) plots A as X axis and B as Y axis

Try following code with your data and let me know the result

```
plot(mtcars$mpg , mtcars$wt, xlab="mpg", ylab = "wt", pch = 19)
abline(lm(wt ~ mpg, mtcars))
```

Comment: Thanks Mandar, it worked with change in abssisa and ordinate.