# Fail to add linear regression line in barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, linear-regression, lm

I have some data about the percentages of temperature for different time periods and I want to create a barplot showing those percentages and then add a linear regression line showing the trend. Although i manage to get the first graph, I fail to add a straight linear regression line

Basically I try to make a barplot with these tx_1 data

`tx_1<-c(0.055,0.051,0.057,0.049,0.061,0.045)`

[image: The plot without the line]

[image: The plot with the non-straight line]

```
mypath<-file.path("C:\\tx5\\1.jpeg")
jpeg(file = mypath,width = 1200, height = 600)
plot.dim<-barplot(get(name),
                  space= 2,
                  ylim=c(0,0.15),
                  main = "Percentage of days when Tmax < 5th percentile",
                  xlab = "Time Periods",
                  ylab = "Percentage",
                  names.arg = c("1975-1984", "1985-1990", "1991-1996", "1997-2002", "2003-2008", "2009-2014"),
                  col = "darkred",
                  horiz = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

I tried using ggplot also, but with no luck

Comment: You can achieve that by first computing the linear model with the `lm` function and then adding the line with the `abline` function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876332/plot-regression-line-abline) for an example). I'm really not sure about the validity of such a model, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have included both a line connecting each observation and a overall best linear fit line. Hope this helps.

```
library(tidyverse)

year <- tribble(~ Year,~ Percent,
        94,0.055,
        95,0.051,
        96,0.057,
        97,0.049,
        98,0.061,
        99,0.045)

ggplot(year,aes(Year,Percent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = F)
```

Comment: if you look at OP's problem, the x-axis labels are categorical.. so if you have that instead of 94,95... can your code still work?